# Creating an Android application supporting Android version 5 and version 9

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Android development. I am told to create an android app that should support android `Version 5` (Lollipop) and android `Version 9` (Pie). How should I approach this? Should i create 2 different apps supporting `Version 5` and `Version 9`?

Is there any way to make a single app that runs on both version 5 and version 9?
If I use `AndroidX`, then will it make sure that the app look and function same on both version 5 and 9?

P.S.: I am told to build the app using Xamarin Android Native (not Xamarin Forms).

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 2):

**First** you need to understand the following Settings:

**Target Framework** :Specifies which framework to use in building your application. This API level is used at compile time by Xamarin.Android.

**Minimum Android Version**:Specifies the oldest Android version that you want your app to support. This API level is used at run time by Android.

**Target Android Version**:Specifies the version of Android that your app is intended to run on. This API level is used at run time by Android.

Normally, all three Xamarin.Android API levels are set to the same value. On the **Application** page, set **Compile using Android version (Target Framework)** to the latest stable API version (or, at a minimum, to the Android version that has all of the features you need)strong text

On the **Android** **Manifest** page, set the **Minimum Android version** to **Use Compile using SDK version** and set the **Target Android version** to the same value as the Target Framework version.

If you want to maintain backward compatibility with an earlier version of Android, set **Minimum Android version** to target to the oldest version of Android that you want your app to support.

**Then** in you case,you could set the `Target Framework version` to `Android 9.0`,and `Minimum Android Version` to `Android 5`,`Target Android Version` to `Android 9.0`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In the last sentence, do u mean to say minimum android version to Android 5? thanks.

Comment: @TajveerSinghNijjar Yes,i wrote the wrong version number.

Comment: @TajveerSinghNijjar Is it helpful to you ?